# difference between field of sets and ring of sets.

Tags: measure-theory

Is it true that the only difference between a ring of sets in measure theory and a field of sets is that a field of sets $\mathcal F$ on $X$ contains $X$ but a ring of sets $\mathcal R$ may or may not contain $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In measure theory, rings of sets  on $X$ is subset of the power set of $X$ which is closed under finite unions and differences.  (This implies that a ring is closed under finite intersection.)  A field of sets on $X$ has (at least) two equivalent characterizations:

- a ring of sets which contains $X$.
- a subset of the power set which contains $X$ or $\emptyset$ and which is closed under finite unions and the complement operation.

So yes, that's the only difference.  (See e.g. http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~derezins/mat-m.pdf)

Comment: by finite unions and intersection do you exclude empty intersection and union?

Comment: A\A is the empty set, so a ring of sets always contains the empty set